# looping over all elements in JSON response PHP

Tags: php, json

After making a cURL call, I get a JSON response back as follows, already decoded as a string.

```
{
  "AAPL": {
    "fundamental": {
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "high52": 229.67,
      "low52": 149.16,
  }
}
```

If I want to loop over all elements in 'fundamental,' what would be the best loop to use for this in PHP? I have tried the `foreach` method, but I was getting an `illegal character use message`.

I also get the error:
`Undefined property: stdClass::$fundamental` when trying:

```
$json_new = json_decode($json);
echo $json_new->fundamental;
```

The current `foreach`:

```
foreach ($json_new as $val){
     echo $val->fundamental;
}
```

Comment: please show your `foreach` code. you have some error there

Comment: @AlivetoDie added in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step-1: decode JSON to array

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

Step-2: loop

```
foreach ($arr['AAPL']['fundamental'] as $key => $val) {
  echo $key . ' = ' . $val . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: this code will not work if your response have multiple keys with array data. like `{
   "AAPL": {
  "fundamental": {
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "high52": 229.67,
    "low52": 149.16
  },
  "Basics": {
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "high52": 39.67,
    "low52": 49.16
  }
 }
}`